# MySQL COUNT on LEFT JOINed table is ignoring none joined records

Tags: mysql, group-by, left-join

I have 3 tables (these are the main fields):

- friend *(stores users' friends)*

  - id_user
  - id_str *(twitter unique ID)*
- user *(stores users)*

  - id_user
  - id_str *(twitter unique ID)*
  - name
- wc_forecast *(stores soccer forecasts of users)*

  - id_forecast
  - id_user

I need to select a list of all the friends form **user ID 3**, and the count of their forecasts as well. This is my current query:

```
SELECT
COUNT(wc_forecast.id_forecast) AS q,
user.name AS name, user.screen_name AS screen_name
FROM user
    JOIN friend ON friend.id_str = user.id_str
    LEFT JOIN wc_forecast ON wc_forecast.id_user = user.id_user
WHERE
    friend.id_user = 3
GROUP BY wc_forecast.id_user
ORDER BY q DESC
```

The problem is that not all the users are being displayed. Specifically those that haven't made any forecasts are not in that list. Oddly only one of them is.

Here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3519c/2) with some example records.

The question is, how can i display a list of all the user's friends, including all those that have no records in wc_forecast as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that if there's no value to group by, it is excluded.

Note that you're grouping by "wc_forecast.id_user" which might or might not exist. If it does exist, you get values. If it doesn't exist, you get nothing. Perhaps you wanted to group by COALESCE( wc_forecast.id_user, user.id_user )? Or simply just group by user.id_user, since they should be the same value if the friend's forecast exists.

```
SELECT
  COUNT(wc_forecast.id_forecast) AS q,
  user.name AS name,
  user.screen_name AS screen_name
FROM user
  JOIN friend ON friend.id_str = user.id_str
  LEFT JOIN wc_forecast
    ON wc_forecast.id_user = user.id_user
WHERE
    friend.id_user = 3
GROUP BY
  user.id_user
ORDER BY
  q DESC
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3519c/12/0

Comment: Thanks! Worked out fine.